# Parametric Plotting

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, parametric-functions

I am trying to make a parametric plot of the x and y displacements of a vibration problem.  When trying to plot the parametric curve won't show up.

[image]

Comment: Could you enter your problem using some [formatting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) so it can be copied for testing?

Comment: Please post code, not just images.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
solx = NDSolve[{x''[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
soly = NDSolve[{y''[t] == -y[t], y[0] == 2, y'[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
ParametricPlot[{x[t] /. solx[[1]], y[t] /. soly[[1]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]